# 2 Node Linux Cluster - Architecture Validation

Tags: linux, cluster, icmp, ip-forwarding

so I have a 2 node galera cluster on single 192.168.10.0/24 IP subnet as on this layout:
[image]

My problem is not about Galera but connectivity. Node1 is unable to reach Node2 via ICMP hence my Galera Cluster isn't working.

A. No FW was activated but I get response from each IP that has a direct cable connection.

B. From my laptop I'm able to reach Server A and Server B interfaces, but can't reach the Galera Node interfaces. Ping's output is "Destination Unreachable".

C. I've enabled ip forwarding on ServerA and B and nothing happened. Next I've setup IPTABLES as follows:

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth3 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth3 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
(*) why eth1 to eth3?  because I was trying to at least reach any machine on the LAN, but no success.

D. Now ping doesn't return back any output like if the FW were filtering it.

E. I've setup no GW for any piece here since they' all belong to the same subnet.

---

QUESTION:  Is this architecture setup properly done? I mean, I thought I could reach Node2 from Node1 and viceversa, for example by following this path:

[image]

Bonus: at this point we can't add any additional networking card to the setup.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: How have you configured the firewall?

Comment: hey!   no, there is no active firewall on the LAN.  I was just playing around with iptables on Server A and B in order to allow ICMP packets to flow but no response.  This is what I've done so far:                                                                         iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth3 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth3 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
(*) why eth1 to eth3?  because I was trying to at least reach any machine on the LAN, but no success.